# Obtaining year and month from date column in R

Tags: r

I have a date column where dates look like this:
19940818
19941215

What is the proper command to extract the year and month from them?

Comment: How do I check whether it is a number or character? I merely want to output another 2 columns, one with the year only and one with the month only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is e.g.

```
(df <- data.frame(date = c("19940818", "19941215")))
#      date
#1 19940818
#2 19941215
```

To add two columns, one for month and one for year, you can do

```
within(df, {
    year <- substr(date, 1, 4)
    month <- substr(date, 5, 6)
})
#       date month year
# 1 19940818    08 1994
# 2 19941215    12 1994
```

I don't see a need to convert to `Date` class here since all you want is a substring of the date column.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `extract` from `tidyr`.  Using `df` from @Richard Scriven's post

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, date, c('year', 'month'), '(.{4})(.{2}).*', remove=FALSE)
#      date year month
#1 19940818 1994    08
#2 19941215 1994    12
```